# Using PuTTY SSH, how do I capture the remote output of a command?

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, putty, stdout

### In Linux

```
ssh me@server "echo this ran remotely"
```

The output `this ran remotely` is put to standard out. This is perfect.

### In Windows

```
echo "echo this ran remotely" > test.cmd
putty -i privatekey.ppk -m test.cmd -ssh me@server
```

The output doesn't go to standard out, it opens in a new process and, as far as I can tell, is lost forever.

How do I capture the output of the remote command?

I know I can do it in cygwin, but that's not helpful because it's hard to run cygwin commands programmatically from other scripting languages.

Comment: Why not enable session logging to a log file? (On session window right-click menu bar > Change settings.)

Comment: Another solution I found was the new `ubuntu` command in windows (See the windows store for "Ubuntu")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what [Plink](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.64/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) is meant for:

```
plink user@host "echo this ran remotely"
```

Comment: Are you asking a question or answering a question. Please elaborate why this answers the question. Include sources which back your claim.

Comment: Do you know if there's a place I can put the private key file so I don't always have to specify it with the `-i` argument?

Comment: @JonathanLeaders No. There's no equivalent of `~/.ssh/id_rsa` in PuTTY toolset. Though you can use [Pageant - authentication agent](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.64/htmldoc/Chapter9.html).

Comment: unfortunately plink with ssh cant work for some reason.